# Newline Inside a String To Be Shown At a TMemoBox

Tags: string, delphi, variables, lazarus, memo

I'm building a `String` called `FullMemo`, that would be displayed at a `TMemoBox`, but the problem is that I'm trying to make newlines like this:

```
FullMemo := txtFistMemo.Text + '\n' + txtDetails.Text
```

What I got is the content of `txtFirstMemo` the character `\n`, not a newline, and the content of `txtDetails`. What I should do to make the newline work?

Comment: duplicated ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254407/how-do-i-include-a-newline-character-in-a-string-in-delphi

Comment: If it's duplicated, so why the answers are totally different?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The solution is to use #13#10 or better as Sertac suggested [sLineBreak](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_sLineBreak.html).

```
FullMemo := txtFistMemo.Text + #13#10 + txtDetails.Text;
FullMemo := txtFistMemo.Text + sLineBreak + txtDetails.Text;
```

Comment: Can also use `sLineBreak`.

Comment: using sLineBreak is the best approach!!

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz - +1 great tip, I haven't noticed something like this

Answer (score 4):

A more platform independent solution would be `TStringList`.

```
var
  Strings: TStrings;
begin
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Strings.Assign(txtFirstMemo.Lines); // Assuming you use a TMemo
    Strings.AddStrings(txtDetails.Lines);
    FullMemo := Strings.Text;
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To Add an empty newline you can use:

```
Strings.Add('');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
FullMemo := txtFistMemo.Text + #13#10 + txtDetails.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare something like this:

```
const 
 CRLF = #13#10; //or name it 'Enter' if you want
 LBRK = CRLF+ CRLF;
```

in a common unit and use it in all your programs. It will be really handy. Now, after 20 years, I have CRLF used in thousands of places!

```
FullMemo := txtFistMemo.Text + CRLF + txtDetails.Text
```

---

**IMPORTANT**
In Windows, the correct format for enters is CRLF not just CR or just LF as others sugges there.
For example Delphi IDe (which is a Windows app) will be really mad at you if your files do not have proper enters (CRLF):
[Delphi XE - All blue dots are shifted with one line up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609898/delphi-xe-all-blue-dots-are-shifted-with-one-line-up)

Answer (score 0):

You don't make newlines like this, you use symbol #13:

```
FullMemo := txtFistMemo.Text + #13 + txtDetails.Text
    + Chr(13) + 'some more text'#13.
```

#13 is CR, #10 is LF, sometimes it's enough to use just CR, sometimes (when writing text files for instance) use #13#10.

Comment: Line break on Windows is always #13#10 (or better sLineBreak as Sertac suggests).

Comment: It's not "always" #13#10. There's no rule saying you cannot parse #13 for linebreak, even on Windows. For instance, MessageBox accepts it just fine.

Comment: @himself - "it just works" is not equivalent to "it is correct". If Delphi editor chateches you with such "half-enters" it will be really mad at you during debugging.