# Delphi - My debugger seems to be out of sync with the source code

Tags: delphi, debugging

I just upgraded to Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and recompiled my application. I am noticing something very strange and was wondering if anyone knew what the issue might be.

My source code seems to be out of sync with the debug info. The blue dots in some units are not aligned with code (some of them are on lines that have no code). See snippet below:
[image: Debug info out of sync with code]

I have tried the following to resolve it (with no success):
1. Project Clean and Rebuild.
2. Deletion of the DPROJ file and recreating by reopening the DPR.
3. Ensuring that the debugging options are set correctly in the Project Options.

Note that this has happened only with some units. Other units/forms seem to be OK. Has anyone else seen this (whether on Tokyo or other versions)? Any thoughts around how I can fix this? I am unable at this time to effectively debug that unit. Any help or guidance would be most appreciated!

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/q/2603077/224704

Comment: @CraigYoung - No - this is not the case. Even if I set the breakpoint on 2 consecutive blue dots neither of them gets triggered.

Comment: There are a number of possible causes that have been discussed on this site. It's your job to find the one that matches your situation and upvote the most helpful answer. This way the most helpful answers will be more easily locatable for others in future.

Comment: @CraigYoung - I agree with you. But I have already done searches on this site and others with no success before posting my question.

Comment: We have no way of helping any further without being on your computer. That's now how we work here. As said, this subject has been discussed many times, and only you know your environment. It sounds like you have some older dcu files somewhere.

Comment: I added some more info and a way to check the line breaks, to the linked answer concerning 'blue dots'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16204032/62576

Comment: Just wanted to close on this. I opened the project in 10.1.2 Berlin and the issue did not persist. When I opened again with Tokyo, the issue came back. Going by some of the comments provided, I took the files that had the issue and opened them individually in Notepad++. For each affected file, I changed the line ending to LF and then back to CRLF and saved them. Now when I reopened the project in Tokyo, and recompiled, the blue dots lined up. TL;DR the issue was with the line endings. Thanks to all that provided guidance in this matter.