# How to fix compilation error: "String exceeds line"

Tags: string, delphi

I am new to Delphi programming. I want to create a simple string variable where it contains a new line inside of it, like this:

```pascal
S := 'MAR 11, 2021  4:38 AM

Ciao';
```

This is the short program.

```
program StrTest;

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;
var
  S : String;
begin
  S := 'MAR 11, 2021  4:38 AM

Ciao';
  writeln(S);
  Readln;

end.
```

But I get this error message:

> String exceeds line

Even if I try to maximize the capacity of the string variable. It looks as though it can't take a new line inside of it, but I need at least one for my test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up two unrelated things.  Line breaks are not permitted within string literals *in source code*, and this is why you are getting the error.  OTOH, they **are** permitted within string **values** at run-time, so you can write

```pascal
S := 'MAR 11, 2021  4:38 AM ' + #13#10 + 'Ciao';
```

Or, more concisely:

```pascal
S := 'MAR 11, 2021  4:38 AM '#13#10'Ciao';
```

Where `#13` is the ASCII code for a "carriage return" and `#10` for a "line feed".  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/254997/2663863 for a better and cross-platform solution based on the predefined `sLineBreak` constant.

Comment: Two minor (possibly helpful) additions: (1) "string values in source code" are technically known as "string literals". (2) Personally, I'm might be a bit of a golfer, but I often use the possibility to write `'alpha' + #13#10 + 'beta'` more succinctly as `'alpha'#13#10'beta'`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @AndreasRejbrand; I've edited them into the answer.

Comment: @ALombardo sLineBreak is already mentioned at the end of the answer